# If Statement with JSON Data from boolean

Tags: java, android, boolean

I have a boolean who is created from `public static boolean checkIfOnline()`. But I want to make a check system (from the value) with `public void detectonline()`. But when I want to call it on `my protected void onCreate`. I have this error : `Unhandled exceptions: org.json.JSONException, java.io.IOException` on my `detectonline();` (in the onCreate).

```
public class notification extends AppCompatActivity  {
  Boolean onair;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_notification);
    detectonline();
  }

  public void detectonline() throws JSONException, IOException {
    checkIfOnline();

    final TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView); // Hors ligne
    final TextView t2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2); // En ligne

    if (onair == false) {
      t.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      t2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
      t.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
      t2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
  }

  public static boolean checkIfOnline() throws JSONException, IOException {
    String channerUrl = "https://api.dailymotion.com/video/x3p6d9r?fields=onair";

    String jsonText = readFromUrl(channerUrl);// reads text from URL

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText); // You create a json object from your string jsonText
    if(json.has("onair")) { // just a simple test to check the node that you need existe
      boolean onair = json.getBoolean("onair"); // In the url that you gave onair value is boolean type
      return onair;
    }

    return false;
  }

  private static String readFromUrl(String url) throws IOException {
    URL page = new URL(url);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Scanner scanner = null;
    try{
      //scanner = new Scanner(page.openStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()); Encodage qui merde avant l'API 19 d'android
      scanner = new Scanner(page.openStream());
      while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
        sb.append(scanner.nextLine());
      }
    } finally {
       if (scanner!=null)
         scanner.close();
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }
}
```

How can I check if the boolean is true or false and how do an action with the result?

Comment: When you throw an exception in Java, you MUST catch it somewhere. It is your responsibility to do that unless you pay an Exception catcher to do it for you!

Answer (score 0):

1. your global variable `onair` is never initialized.

   `onair = checkIfOnline();`
2. Method `detectionline()` throws `JSONException` and `IOException` so whenever you call this method you have to deal with this kind of exceptions, either by catching them or by re-throwing them

```
    try{
         detectionline();
    }catch(JSONException | IOException e){
         e.printstacktrace();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, your checkIfOnline() function returns boolean but you're using it as a void i.e. not assigning the return value anywhere. So change this

```
public static boolean checkIfOnline()
```

to this

```
public static void checkIfOnline()
```

Second, inside the checkIfOnline() function, you're assigning the value to of boolean to the local variable onair as you're declaring the boolean in the function itself over here:

```
boolean onair = json.getBoolean("onair");
```

So just change it to:

```
onair = json.getBoolean("onair");
```

And last thing, declare the onair variable as a private/public variable so that the functions can modify it (And also, use boolean not Boolean as written in your code above). So change this

```
Boolean onair;
```

to this

```
private static boolean onair;
```

This might fix the issues. If not, I'll give you a better answer, but try this first.

Comment: Thank you for you help, but in `protected void onCreate`, when i want call ` detectonline();` i have the same problem `Unhandled exceptions: org.json.JSONException, java.io.IOException`